# Finding the exact position of a graphical object in relation to some other Canvas

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox, and when I select an item in that ListBox I want  to duplicate the image and place it on the Canvas containing all the other objects in my app.  This works fine for the most part, however if the item in the ListBox is further in, such that I have to scroll to see the item, the coordinates are no longer accurate.

Is there a function such as Canvas.getGlobalPosition(UIElement), which would allow me to then set Canvas.SetTop(uiElement, globalCoordinateSpace.Y) and allow me to perfectly place one image directly ontop of the other, no matter where in the ListBox it resides?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [TransformToVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.transformtovisual%28VS.95%29.aspx) to create transform that allows you to determine the location of one element with respect to another.

I often use the following extension method to allow me to determine the relative position of two `UIElements`:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the relative position of the given UIElement to this.
    /// </summary>
    public static Point GetRelativePosition(this UIElement element, UIElement other)
    {
        return element.TransformToVisual(other)
                      .Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    }
```

You can get the exact on-screen position by invoking the above code on `Application.Current.RootFrame`.

Comment: Thanks @ColinE, I'm a bit confused about the "this" in the method argument.  Would I use this method like such:  SomeClass.GetRelativePosition(selectedItemInListbox, Application.Current.RootFrame); ?

Comment: It is an extension method, you don't need to include the first method argument. The GetRelativePosition extension method will be present on any UIElement.

Comment: So I used it like this:  selectedItemInListbox.GetRelativePosition(selectedItemInListbox, Application.Current.RootFrame);  or like this:   selectedItemInListbox.GetRelativePosition(Application.Current.RootFrame);

Comment: Other way round I think Application.Current.RootFrame.GetRelativePosition(selectedItemInListbox);

Comment: Hi ColinE, Thanks for the answer. I was able to fix some issues, but unfortunately, the position it returns is not correct.  I also seem to be getting a the wrong item from the ListBox, as it gives me the source and not the actual visual object on the screen?

Comment: The correct usage of the function ended up being selectedItemContainer.GetRelativePosition(Application.Current.RootFrame);