# How do I get access to the item in a ListBox that is being rendered rather than its source data?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

In a continuation from my [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9179142/787202)

I tried using the solution provided in the linked answer, however when I give it the image which the ListBox is binding to, it gives me the wrong position, because the Item Template is loading in a source URL rather than the actual image, and it seems the data is null.

My Item Template looks like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 

                     Height="64" Name="listBoxSource" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                     SelectionChanged="listBoxSource_SelectionChanged" Canvas.Left="32" Canvas.Top="365" Width="596"
             >

                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image x:Name="ListImage" Source="{Binding thumbnailURL}" Height="64" Width="64"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            </ListBox>
```

How do I get access to "ListImage" for the currently selected Item?

Comment: Why do you need the Image? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: @Erno I want to find it's global position on the phone's screen, as related to my linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every ItemsControl has an ItemsContainerGenerator, which (surprisingly enough) is responsible for generating a control for each item in the list. It provides a few useful methods for finding the container of a given item, and vice versa. You can use it like this:

```
private void listBoxSource_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var listBox = (ListBox) sender;
    var containerGenerator = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator;
    var container = (UIElement)containerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(listBox.SelectedItem);
}
```

You can then use the variable *container* with the solution from your other post to find the coordinates,

```
Point position = container.GetRelativePosition(Application.Current.RootVisual);
```

And on a side note, in your DataTemplate you don't need the StackPanel, since the ListBox is providing that with its ItemsPanelTemplate.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image x:Name="ListImage" Source="{Binding thumbnailURL}" Height="64" Width="64"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Trying this now, thanks.  It seemed to work, but for some reason it's telling me that the position of the Image is -352 when its in the middle of the screen.  Any ideas whats going on there?

Comment: Nevermind, the guy in the other answer gave me the input backwards :)  Thanks a ton for this! Wish I could give an extra +1

Comment: Yeah, it was backwards. I'll fix my answer (and maybe simplify it a bit).

Answer (score 1):

on tap event you can do this:

private void image_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)

```
{
            Image selectedImage = e.OriginalSource as Image;
}
```

is this what you need?

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and get back here.

Comment: That almost seemed to work, but adding a tap event to the image seems to cause the selectedItem event to not work properly. I think they run in the wrong order to be useful.

Comment: I gave it an upvote, it was most certainly helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different solution because the way you are trying to solve it (finding the control) is prone to error.

Make the DataTemplate a resource and refer to it in the ListBox by using `ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"`

Next, when an item is selected, add a ContentControl to the Canvas, set its ContentTemplate to the same DataTemplate and the DataContext to the SelectedItem.

This way you only have to define the template once (one place to maintain it) and do not have to walk the VisualTree.

Comment: Can you explain how this will give me a reference to the rendered item so I can figure out it's global position?  Won't this re-position the content and rendred item to 0,0 or whatever?

Comment: It will not give you the position of the rendered item. If you want to put something on top just put the Image in the template in a Grid, add yet another image in the same grid and set its Source to a secondImageUrl. Then, when an Item is selected set the secondImageUrl property of the selectedItem. Try to stay away from manipulating the UI, use binding instead.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will help me make my app better, but for this specific piece of it, I need an item duplicated in the same spot that it's been selected so it can be dragged around and played with by the user.